# Insert an array into state using useState hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm a newbie to React. Trying to insert an array of data into a variable using `useState()` hook in a functional component. When I do this, I was getting this error

```
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0 or more.ts(2556)
```

**Code**

```
const data = [{
  title: 'React',
  'description': 'State in React'
}, {
  title: 'Angular',
  'description': 'Introducing Typescript'
}]

const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

setPosts(data)
```

Could anyone please help?

Comment: If you want `posts` to start out like that, just do `const [posts, setPosts] = useState(data);`

Comment: Wow, that worked! But, why can't it set it the above way?@ChrisG

Comment: You need to provide a proper [mre]; but I don't think you're supposed to drop a `setX` statement in the component function like that. I'll also recommend using classes first, to learn all the basics. Hooks can be quite difficult if you're a react beginner.

Comment: you probably have conflicting versions of `react-dom` and `react` depencencies. Make sure they are the same version.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple functional component "Home" based on your code and it works correctly. The code is below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const data = [
    {
      title: 'React',
      description: 'State in React'
    },
    {
      title: 'Angular',
      description: 'Introducing Typescript'
    }
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setPosts(data)}>
        Data
      </button>
      <div>
        Data from State:
        {posts.map((obj) => {
          return <div key={obj.title}>{obj.title}</div>
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

If this answere was helpful please mark it.